# Serialization restrictions in .net

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize an object that is an instance of a pretty complex class - class that consists of other complex classes. I am getting an error about reflecting. I am trying to decorate every member with XMLElement tag but it's just too much of work, especially that I am doing some experimental UI work and backend is not important at this point. As long as it works. Is there a way of making serialization just working without going and modifying tons of existing code?

Thanks

Comment: Would help if you explained the error you are getting, and showing some code of how you serialize/deserialize.

Comment: There was an error reflecting type 'myType'

Comment: Check the `InnerException`, it should have more information

Comment: See also here: [Troubleshooting Common Problems with the XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx#trblshtxsd_topic6)

Comment: Yes, It complains about  myType's member. After decorating it it would complain about members in the member. And it goes on and on, and on.

Comment: You don't need to add `XmlElement` attributes as long as the property names match the desired XML element names.  See also here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Can you edit and update the question to show the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including the traceback and inner exceptions?

Comment: Does it have to be XML?   Binary serialization has fewer restrictions and is typically a lot easier to set up.